# How can I check the number of programs which connects to same D-Bus?

Tags: qt, dbus

I'm currently using D-Bus communications to connect several programs.
I matched the D-Bus adress with three programs.
Two are using QT example Chat, and Other is using QT example ping-pong.
The two program using QT Chat connects perfectly, but I can't connect ping pong file with other two file.

So, I want to check how many programs are connected in specific D-Bus address.

Can anyone help me?

My Dbus adress is `"org.example.chat"`

Comment: This may be helpful https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46309/146662